# Could not open the requested SVN filesystem on windows7

Tags: apache, svn

while configuring apache httpd with subversion on windows 7, getting below error.. 
i had already installed with different types of versions of SVN and apache also still im facing this issue.. could please some one help me out of this issue..

```
svn, version 1.9.1 (r1698128)        `compiled Sep  1 2015, 19:50:43 on x86-microsoft-windows`
httpd-2.2.22-win32-x86-openssl-0.9.8t,
Server version: Apache/2.2.22 (Win32)
Server built:   Jan 28 2012 11:16:39
```

and previously i had installed svn for 1.8.18 and httpd-2.2.25-win32-x86-openssl-0.9.8y

i copied these below files to apache/conf/httpd

```
LoadModule  dav_module             modules/mod_dav.so
LoadModule dav_fs_module        modules/mod_dav_fs.so 
LoadModule  dav_svn_module         modules/mod_dav_svn.so
LoadModule  authz_svn_module       modules/mod_authz_svn.so
```

Getting below   Error:

```
    This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
    <D:error xmlns:D="DAV:" xmlns:m="http://apache.org/dav/xmlns" xmlns:C="svn:">
<C:error/>        <m:human-readable errcode="160043">Could not open the requested SVN filesystem</m:human-readable>
</D:error>
```

Comment: I've just updated the answer. It seems that you have different versions of SVN installed on the machine. Client and admin tools are on 1.9 version, the server components are on 1.8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first, show your full httpd.conf file and see what's logged to Apache log. I guess that you'll understand the root cause by looking through the log.

Next, if you have troubles setting up SVN+Apache server on Windows yourself, search the web for prepackaged all-in-one solutions. E.g. google "svn server windows". Otherwise, check the [official binary packages page](https://subversion.apache.org/packages.html#windows).

**Update:**

The most interesting part of the logged error is:

```
E160043: Expected FS format between '1' and '6'; found format '7'
```

The error means that you have Subversion 1.8 installed as your server. However, the repository was created using Subversion 1.9 tools and has newer format. You should make sure that your server is on the most current version 1.9 or create the repository using 1.8 tools. There is another option that may help you: create the repository using `svnadmin create REPOSITORY --compatible-version 1.8` command.

The fact that when you run `svn --version` you see `version 1.9.1 (r1698128)` just means that your command-line client has version 1.9.1. This is irrelevant to the server side.

Comment: log file has shown below error
[Sun Jan 03 17:22:59 2016] [notice] Child 3692: Starting thread to listen on port 80.
[Sun Jan 03 17:23:21 2016] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] (20014)Internal error: Expected FS format between '1' and '6'; found format '7'
[Sun Jan 03 17:23:41 2016] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Could not fetch resource information.  [500, #0]
[Sun Jan 03 17:23:41 2016] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] Could not open the requested SVN filesystem  [500, #160043]

Comment: provided svn location as follows 
<Location /svn>
DAV svn
SVNPath C:/repositories/repo1
</Location>